# SAML SSO - how does it work with multiple service providers

Tags: c#, saml, saml-2.0

I'm tasked with developing an SSO system with SAML. I have to login to the identity provider (via a mobile app) and redirect to my site after authentication.

After some research I think understand the interaction between a Service Provider and an ID Provider and how a user's identity is confirmed.

But what happens when I redirect the user to another Service Provider? How can I transfer the authenticated user's identity to my site without login once again with Identity Provider.

Must I send the SAML assertion tokens along with the redirect request?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. This happens seamlessly if you use [service provider-initiated SSO flow](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/Post2.0/sstc-saml-tech-overview-2.0-cd-02.html#5.1.1.Introduction%7Coutline).

[image]

When you try to access a resource on any SAML-speaking service provider, if you're not authenticated at the service provider, you'll be redirected back to the identity provider. Let's say this is the first time it happened. Identity provider would prompt for authentication and following that it would send a SAML response to the service provider. Now you try to access a resource on another SAML service provider. You would again be redirected to the identity provider but this time you won't be prompted for authentication as long as your security context (session..) at the identity provider is still alive. The identity provider will silently send a SAML response to the second service provider.

Comment: Thanks for answer. When I try to access a resource on another SAML service provider, What must I request to the identity provider? Is the first time redirect to identity provider same? The first time I login on a mobile app.

Comment: You don't need to request anything as long as the relationship/trust is established between the identity provider and the service provider and the service provider supports SP-initiated SSO. When you access the resource on a SP, it'll send a SAML authentication request to the identity provider. The identity provider will reply to this request with a SAML response.

Comment: I mean that, second time "When you access the resource on a SP, it'll send a SAML authentication request to the identity provider.". Is second time authentication request the same with first time authentication request?(after redirect to second site from mobile app). I cannot imagine that how identity provider can identify App and website has been login by one man without something like token (example only).

Comment: The 2nd authentication request will be structurally the same as the 1st one but it'll have different values. For example, one difference will be the identity of the service provider (Issuer element).

Comment: @identigral What if I have IDP initiated flow?